# Can an 'on form submit' script run faster than the form writes to spreadsheet?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a form that sends data to a spreadsheet.
I have a script attached to the form that creates calendar entries, confirmation docs etc on form submit.

On 3 occasions (out of maybe 100 form submits and a pile of manual script runs) the script has run, but rather than pulling the data from the newly submitted form, the data pulled was from the form submit before that. After rechecking the code, the only thing I can figure is that the 'read data from last row of spreadsheet' command was executing before the spreadsheet had 'received' the new form data.

Is this possible? 
(I would have assumed that the on form submit script would not start until the form had been fully submitted as it were)

Is there a way to avoid this kind of hiccup? (I am going to put a 1 sec sleep on the script to give some extra time for the spreadsheet to catch up just in case)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can certainly happen, reading and writing from the sheets takes time and the two actions can occur at different speeds.

Rather than use "getLastRow()" to pull the submitted data, use the Event data passed into your  function by the trigger:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){     //e is an event object passed to the function when it is triggered.
    Logger.log(e.response);   //e.response  is a FormResponse object containing the data submitted by the user.
    Logger.log(e.response.getItemResponses()); //getItemResponses() returns all the responses in an Array, similar to what is returned by getLastRow()

}
```

See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response

Comment: Thanks Cameron, I was stuck in my paradigm of 'get data from the spreadsheet' I didn't even see this simple solution. It will mean moving any formulas that are performed on the spreadsheet into the script, and gives me the excuse to learn how to write objects back to the spreadsheet as a bundle. Thanks